# Facebook SDK giving error of duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have been trying to solve this for a long time but I didn't get anything. So can you please help. 
[image]

Comment: Please double check you have probably added the files twice.

Comment: yes , i have checked it multiple times but unable to find the actual cause.@NeverHopeless

Comment: How did you add the SDK ? Can you please search files like `FBSDKAppEvents` in the navigator to see how many instances are currently exists in project ?

Comment: here's only one instance for every classes of FB SDK. I added three framework which FB SDK says CoreKit , Login and Share

Comment: After long time to understand, i added other linker flags for BOLT and Facebook SDK , then it works.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you delete the current FBSdk and use the another one. I faced the same problem 1 month ago as I was using Paypal sdk and got stuck in the same prob. I deleted the paypal sdk and downloaded the another one. After this my problem was resolved.

Comment: i made a sample project with latest SDK , but got stuck with this duplicate issue and i cross check my project but there's no duplicate file.

I added three framework as FB sdk says 
1. FBSDKCoreKit
2. FBSDKLoginKit
3. FBSDKShareKit

Comment: @karan this can't be totally true. As I was unable to find the duplicate file  when I was using Paypal SDK ,I simply replaced my sdk with the another one. Whydon't you Give a try once more and then tell me

Comment: I am tried your solutions , but no help. It's continously gives the same error.

Comment: Why dont  you try a demo first for Facebook integration.If it's working finr then problem exists in your folder . Make a Demo. And may be the Sdk u r using is not ok.

Comment: After adding the linker flags for BOLT and Facebook SDK , then it comes to work.

Answer (score 0):

facebook sdk version issue ，download the zip file FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813.zip

will resolve your problem . I have resolve it .